# aws-sdk TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-s3-client

I am uploading excel blob to s3 bucket using the S3Client and Upload, In the start it was okay, but now from last week it is giving error that URL is not a constructor, i tried to debug it didn't find the root cause, i am initializing the client outside the function and remaining code inside the function.

```
const client = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: config.s3.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.s3.secretAccessKey,
  },
  region: 'eu-west-2',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});


  let s3blob = await workbook.outputAsync();

            const upload = new Upload({
                  client: client,
                    params: {
                    Bucket: 'bucketName',
                    Key:`reports/${_filename}`,
                    Body: s3blob,
                    ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                }
            });

            upload.on('httpUploadProgress', (p) => console.log(p));

            upload.done()
            .then(response=>{
                res.send(response)
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                res.status(500).send('error');
            })
```

it works sometimes and sometimes it gives the following error.

[image]